# How to set vertical alignment in jface tableviewer?

Tags: swt, alignment, jface, tableviewer

I created a jface CheckboxTableviewer and set its row height to 40px.

But in windows xp, the checkbox is not aligning to the middle.

How can I change the alignment?

```
public class TableTest extends Dialog {

    public TableTest(Shell parent) {
       super(parent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configureShell(Shell newShell) {
        super.configureShell(newShell);
        newShell.setText("CheckboxTableViewer");
        newShell.setSize(500,300);
    }

    @Override
    protected Control createDialogArea(Composite parent) {
        Composite container =  (Composite) super.createDialogArea(parent);
        container.setLayout(new FillLayout());

        CheckboxTableViewer tbv = CheckboxTableViewer.newCheckList(container, SWT.BORDER|SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
        Table table = tbv.getTable();
        table.setLinesVisible(true);
        table.addListener(SWT.MeasureItem, new Listener() {
            @Override
            public void handleEvent(Event e) {
                e.height = 40;
            }
        });

        tbv.setContentProvider(new ArrayContentProvider());

        List<String> inputs = new ArrayList<String>();
        inputs.add("One");
        inputs.add("Two");
        inputs.add("Three");

        tbv.setInput(inputs);


        return container;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TableTest t = new TableTest(new Shell());
        t.open();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have spend lot of time on this, but it seems like bug in windows API.. You should make bug report on [SWT Bugzilla](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/bugs.php)..

Comment: Works on MacOS with Eclipse 3.6

Comment: Works on Linux Mint 11 (Ubuntu fork) as well, so it's definitely Win XP API bug..

Comment: Thanks guys. Currently I have to use checkboxcelleditor and set a larger image to the column.